# Spring Data multiple jpa-named-queries.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm externalize sql queries by using named queries on file `META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties`.

Since I have many queries, it will be good to create multiple properties file, e.g.:

- `META-INF/jpa-named-queries-product.properties`
- `META-INF/jpa-named-queries-logistic.properties`
- `META-INF/jpa-named-queries-payment.properties`

How can I achieve this on Spring Data? `@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "")` only receive one parameter.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?